# Best way to design subscription expiration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, database-design

I'm redesigning our subscription model and wonder what is the best design pattern:

Model 1:

User has a billing date.

On top of the billing date, user is assigned a specific expiry date. The expiry date = signup_date + subscription_length .

The authorization system authorizes access if current_time() is less than the expiry_date.

Model 2:

User has a billing date.

The authorization system authorizes access if User subscription status = active.

Using Cronjob, user's subscription status is changed from active to expired if current_time > billing_date

Comment: Go with #1. #2 can fail more easily, and you're storing redundant data (status can be determined from billing date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model 1 is good because you only do the evaluation when you need to, i.e. when someone is trying to access something, it is very efficient and saves a cron job. Cron jobs can be a pain to administer and can create problems with scaling,

Model 2 has the advantage that you find out when sessions expire (or not long after) i.e. there is a guaranteed event around expiry.  This might be a good thing, e.g. if you want to send an email saying that a subscription has expired or you want to know how many subscriptions are still active.  Of course there are other models which could get these features too.

Answer (score 2):

Model 1 is better with one modification: `expiry date = subscription_date + subscription_length` - and not `signup_date` since signup date is always the first time the user signs up (usually). But they will re-subscribe repeatedly (hopefully). There may also be a gap after the expiration that the user re-subscribes, so then they'll lose time on their new subscription if you only add subscription length to the sign-up date.

Model 2, as @Will pointed out, is a good way to find which users will have their subscriptions expiring soon.

Answer (score 1):

I personally feel that *Model 1* is a better approach here.
Even if a user extends his subscription in between, you can safely apply a callback and set appropriate `expiry_date`.
This will work without any bottleneck on background jobs which are anticipated by cron in *Model 2*.

I would love to learn the views of more experienced devs in this question. :)